# How to fix the problem of passing the value of the select to the server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have React app. In this app I have page with list of image categories which I get from local server and **second page with posts**. I also created a `form` that adds **new post** in local server. In this form I have four `input` : ( `title`, `category_id`, `description`, `image`).

In input `category_id` I write number `id` of category. But now I need that there was not `input` but there was `select` with titles of category, which I get from server using API method `GET`. And I tried to make such a select.

But my server response **error**:

#### Category_id is required

It's happening because:

- I pass to the server `title` category, but I should pass `Id` category. Title should be just show us **name** post in `select` but I pass `id` to server.
- Component `SelectCategory` not related with `FormData`. Therefore value which is selected `SelectCategory`  will not appear in `FormData` and then will not appear in `body` method `handleSubmit`.

## How to fix this problem?

---

#### response from serever(list of categories which I get in `const data`):

```
{"data":
[{"id":20,"title":"auto"},
{"id":21,"title":"sport"},
{"id":23,"title":"new"}
]}
```

#### AddPost.js:

```
const AddPost = () => {

      const formRef = useRef();
      const [category, setCategory] = useState('');          // <-- category which I select in select will fall here
      const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);      // <-- a list of existing categories will fall here
  
      useEffect(() => {
           fetchData(); 
      }, []);
    
    async function fetchData() {                                    // <-- get List of categories
        const data = await api(`${listRoute}`, {  method: 'GET'});
        setCategories(data.data.map(item => item.title));          // <-- now I set title of category in select
    }

   const handleSubmit = async (event) => {                // <-- send form to local server
       const data = new FormData(formRef.current);        // <-- value from my from will fall here 
       event.preventDefault();
              const response = await apiImage(`${imageRoute}`, {
                 method: 'POST',
                 body: data,    
              });};
    
   const upadateSelectCategory = e => {       // <-- choose category in select in form
        setCategory(e.target.value);
   };
      
   return (  
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} ref={formRef}>
          <input type="text" name="title"/>
          <input type="text" name="description"/>
          <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*"/>
        /*<input type="text" name="category_id"/>*/      // <-- Instead this input now I write SelectCategory:
          <SelectCategory upadateSelectCategory={upadateSelectCategory} categories={categories} value={category} />
          
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
   </div>
   );
};
```

#### SelectCategory.js:

```
export default (props) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={props.upadateSelectCategory} value={props.value}>
          <option value="">-- Category --</option>
          {props.categories.map(item => <option key={item}>{item}</option>)}  
        </select> 
      </div>
  );}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to send category_id and what now you are store is only title.

You have to store id, too.

```
async function fetchData() {
  const data = await api(`${listRoute}`, {  method: 'GET'});
  setCategories(data.data); // Change here
}
```

and In your `SelectCategory` component:

```
export default (props) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={props.upadateSelectCategory} value={props.value}>
          <option value="">-- Category --</option>
          {props.categories.map(item => <option value={item.id} key={item.id}>{item.title}</option>)}  
        </select> 
      </div>
  );}
```

here set category_id as value of option.

and in `handleSubmit` add this code after `const data = new FormData(formRef.current);`:

```
data.append('category_id', category)
```

Comment: Also server response error: `Category_id is required`

Comment: now in FormData:
http://i.piccy.info/i9/be7025025f126caf92127440e84461fe/1589743079/8778/1372209/formData.png but it must be like this:
http://i.piccy.info/i9/4063de7cdabed457cba4842de5d02f41/1589743152/17949/1372209/formData2.jpg That is, component SelectCategory is not related with `FormData`

Comment: Thank you very much!